# Comparing arrays inside multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Basically i want to compare arrays inside a multidimensional array,
So i want to compare everyone with etc category 1 against each other, category 2 against earch other etc etc.

So what i really want to do is:

Compare every category against each other with this formula

versus - won = x

And then find out who has the lowest number and then update that last survivor from each category in the database (The winners)

Any ideas on how i can solve this the best?

```
$arr;
$stmt = $dbCon->prepare(" SELECT versus, won, imgId, category FROM rating_versus ");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($versus, $won, $imgId, $category);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $arr[] = array('category' => $category, 'id' => $imgId, 'versus' => $versus, 'won' => $won);
//        echo $imgId . "<br> Versus: " . $versus . "<br> Won: " . $won . "<br> <br>";
    }
$stmt->close();
```

This will output something like this

```
array(9) { 
[0]=> array(4) { ["category"]=> int(1) ["id"]=> int(1) ["versus"]=> int(42) ["won"]=> int(21) } 
[1]=> array(4) { ["category"]=> int(1) ["id"]=> int(5) ["versus"]=> int(47) ["won"]=> int(24) } 
[2]=> array(4) { ["category"]=> int(1) ["id"]=> int(13) ["versus"]=> int(47) ["won"]=> int(23) } 
[3]=> array(4) { ["category"]=> int(2) ["id"]=> int(2) ["versus"]=> int(45) ["won"]=> int(19) } 
[4]=> array(4) { ["category"]=> int(2) ["id"]=> int(4) ["versus"]=> int(49) ["won"]=> int(25) } 
[5]=> array(4) { ["category"]=> int(2) ["id"]=> int(7) ["versus"]=> int(44) ["won"]=> int(25) } 
[6]=> array(4) { ["category"]=> int(3) ["id"]=> int(3) ["versus"]=> int(47) ["won"]=> int(29) } 
[7]=> array(4) { ["category"]=> int(3) ["id"]=> int(6) ["versus"]=> int(50) ["won"]=> int(18) } 
[8]=> array(4) { ["category"]=> int(3) ["id"]=> int(9) ["versus"]=> int(45) ["won"]=> int(24) } 
}
```

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: The problem is i cant find anything on this subject, everything is about two arrays or comparing two different multidimensionel arrays and nothing like the way i am trying to do it :) so a pointer would be very helpfull since i dont know where to go with this

Comment: So i am struggling with how the logic with a problem like this is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the winner, you don't need to eliminate one by one, who has the lowest score.

Winner is who has the highest score.

So your code should be like following

```
$arr; $stmt = $dbCon->prepare(" SELECT versus, won, imgId, category FROM rating_versus ");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($versus, $won, $imgId, $category);
$winners=array();
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $arr[] = array('category' => $category, 'id' => $imgId, 'versus' => $versus, 'won' => $won);
     if(isset($winners[$category])) {
          $curmax = $winners[$category]['won'];
          if($won>$curmax) {
                $winners[$category] = array('id'=>$imgId, 'won' => $won);
          }
     } else {
         $winners[$category] = array('id'=>$imgId, 'won' => $won);
    } 
//        echo $imgId . "<br> Versus: " . $versus . "<br> Won: " . $won . "<br> <br>";
} 
$stmt->close();
print_r($winners);
```

This should work for this case

Comment: @iiiml0sto1 I didn't understand clearly, but if you want to find the id with lowest score, for each category, then I will update the code. Is it this what you need?

Comment: Hmm its because some might be votet more than the rest so to make it fair i have to come up with a solution.. but i will modify this to whatever solution i may comeup with.

But thanks for showing me how to solve a logical problem like this, it makes alot of sence to just make an array and update it if the data is greater than the data in the array :)

Comment: No its all fine, it does not make sence to find the lowest score it wount make it all fair anyway :)

Comment: @iiiml0sto1 yes you can work on that, and if this solved your problem please don't forget to click 'accept as answer' 